# cant understand raycasting math from tut code

Tags: 3d, raycasting

forgive me in advance for my ignorance in math . i haven't found any sources that would help me else i wouldn't have opened this topic

i want to create a simple ray-casting engine in javascript, i handled the tile system it wasn't to hard and i had experience with that in the past.

my sources http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/raycast/index.html 
and
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/creating-pseudo-3d-games-with-html-5-can-1/

my problem is understanding most of the math, i understand some of the trig he used (in the second link), but i dont undestand most of his implantation of raycasting.

like this line:
`// where on the screen does ray go through?`

```
    `var rayScreenPos = (-numRays/2 + i) * stripWidth;`
```

pos of what? xy cordinates? lins on screen?

`castSingleRay` i understand some of the math but not the slop or "vertical map/wall lines"he is talking about.

what do i need to learn to understand it? what topics in math or programing? any good books i can download or an online source?

Answer (score 0):

The best way how to understand basic raycasting would really be reading [that great article](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/raycast/index.html) whole.

Anyway, the equation you're talking about is from [step 3 finding walls](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/raycast/rayc6.html#FINDING%20WALLS). As the [part about FOV](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/raycast/rayc5.html) (field of view) explaning, the result image might be divided into vertical parts (called strips in opera tutorial), which might have different size in px (the opera tutorial uses 4px width).

Then you're trying to find out what `x` coordinate on the screen is your current stripe in px (the stripe your currently use to raycast calculations). That's the `rayScreenPos` variable. You might determine the value (`x` position in px for recall), by taking left `x` axis boundary `-numRays/2` (according that as viewer your looking to middle stripe, not the most left one!) plus current stripe `i`, multiplied by size of the strip in pixels `stripWidth`.

Then you can easily calculate viewers distance from just calculated stripe. So you'll use Pythagorean theorem and calculate `rayViewDist`.

**EDIT**

My first raytracer took me few weeks of implementation (so I understand your despair), but after that all just click into place. By viewer I mean 'position of camera'. In the opera dev tut is FOV = 60, stripeSize = 4px, then number of rays is numberOfStripesInImage = sizeOfImage / sizeOfSplice -> 320/4 -> 80 rays.. Then the first rayScreenPos is (-80/2 + 0) * 4 -> -160 which is x position relative to screen center at middle stripe (views is looking in center of screen)

Comment: i kinda understand how raycasting works,the implemntation is the hard part.
but you cleard some of it for me thank you

Comment: and what did you mean by viewer?

Comment: rayScreenPos of the first ray is 160, so its the x on the sceen? but every strip is 4 px.

i still cant get it.

i programed 2d games before my biggest bone was a tower defence.

any way is there any modern easy to understand source?(you know like a book.

Comment: You might look on some raytracer's code, but it's usually the hard way.. Forgot the raycasting and write usual basic raytracer, then you'll get all the nuances..

Comment: I GOT INTO TRIGONOMETRY TOO, RAYTRACING I READ ABOUT IT IS IT THE SAME?

Comment: Difference between raytracing and raycasting is, that raycasting stops tracing down when first hits occurs. This looks like more simple that raytracing, but allows to make some dirty optimizations for speedup, and that complicates code (for understanding) usually a lot..

Comment: Try to read this tutorial http://devmaster.net/posts/2836/raytracing-theory-implementation-part-1-introduction may bring more sense to your project..

Answer (score 0):

Check my tutorial. I'm trying to create a perfect explanation for everything. I'm not using hard render methods, or hard logics for this. I'm studing the RayCasting logic and selecting just the easy things, because for me, simple is best! I think it will help you.

Click [here](https://github.com/vinibiavatti1/RayCastingTutorial/wiki) to access the tutorial. It is in the github wiki.

[image]